# R VGAM package: fit is poorer after adding the second explanatory vairable

Tags: r, spline, data-fitting, vgam

Why does the fit get worse after adding the second explanatory variable?

```
require("VGAM")
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), y = c(1,4,8,15,25,36,48,65,80,105), z =        c(0,0,0,1,100,400,900,1600,1800,200)  )
vgt1 = vgam(y~s(x, df=2), data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)
vgt2 = vgam(y~cbind(s(x, df=2),s(z, df=2)), data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)

plot(df$x, df$y, col="black")
lines(df$x, vgt1@predictors, col="red")
lines(df$x, vgt2@predictors, col="blue")
```

Comment: Why are you creating a matrix when adding the second predictor? why not simply `vgt2 = vgam(y~s(x, df=2)+s(z, df=2), data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)`?

Comment: @mnel, I thought this is the way I should pass my arguments. What does it compute then when I pass the matrix?..

Comment: see my answer for a full description of what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a variable you use `+` not cbind.

`vgam` parses the formula using `terms.formula` to look for `specials = 's'`, i.e. terms that are wrapped in `s` signifying a spline.

Therefore

```
vgt2 = vgam(y~s(x, df=2)+s(z, df=2), data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)
```

will give you what you want (and this has a lower deviance than `vgt1`).

When you fit

```
vgt2 = vgam(y~cbind(s(x, df=2),s(z, df=2)), data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)
```

`terms.formula` doesn't find any `specials` that start with `s`, as `cbind` is the function that identifies the term in the formula. Therefore

```
gam(y~cbind(s(x, df=2),s(z, df=2)), data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)
```

is the equivalent of

```
gam(y~cbind(x,y), data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)
```

which in term is the equivalent of

```
vgam(y~x+z, data=df,family=gaussianff, trace=TRUE)
```

i.e. no spline terms are fitted.